# Show weekdays in TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit

In the log messages dialog of tortoisegit, dates are written without weekday.

[image]

as opposed to TortoiseSVN

[image]

Can I have weekdays shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to TortoiseGit settings to the Dialogs 1 tab and deselect "Short date/time-formats in log messages".

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-dialogs